# Bootstrap 4 - Rails 5 Dropdown menu doesn' t work on mobile phone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with the dropdown list in the following navbar code. 
The menu `<button>...</button>` works on mobile and on desktop.
Only the `<li class="nav-item dropdown">`doesn't work on phone?

Using Rails 5.2.2
Bootstrap  4.2.1

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light nav-upper-clients">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <%= link_to "MarketWeb", root_path,  class:"navbar-brand" %>
   <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <% Category.order('title ASC').all.each do |cat| %>
         <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to  "#{cat.title} ", clients_category_path(cat), class: "nav-link" %></li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <% if current_user %>
            <%= current_user.first_name %>
          <% else %>
              Mon Compte
          <% end %>
          </a>
         <% if current_user %>
           <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
             <%= link_to "Mes adresses", clients_myaddresses_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
             <%= link_to "Mes commandes", clients_orders_path, class: "dropdown-item"  %>
             <%= link_to "Mes favoris", clients_favorites_path, class: "dropdown-item"  %>
             <%= link_to "Déconnection", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :data => { :no_turbolink => true },class: "dropdown-item" %>
           </div>
        <% else %>
           <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
             <%= link_to "Connection", new_user_session_path, class: "dropdown-item"  %>
           </div>           
         <% end %>
       </li>

       <li class= "nav-link">
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <%= link_to clients_cart_path do %>
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>  
          <% end %>
          <% if @current_cart.items_count > 0 %>
            <span id="items_count"><%= @current_cart.items_count %></span>
          <% end %>
        </div>
       </li>
       <% if current_user %>
         <li class="nav-link" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
           <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <%= link_to clients_favorites_path do %>
              <i class="fa fa-heart nav-heart"></i>  
              <% if @favorites.count > 0 %>
                <span id="likes_counter"><%= @favorites.count %></span>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
         </li>
       <% end %>
       <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
         <li class="nav-link">
           <%= link_to  "Site admin", admin_products_path %>
         </li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>

 </div>
</nav>
```

here is the html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light nav-upper-clients">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MarketWeb</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/4">Accessoires </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/5">Chemises </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/2">Pantalons </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/1">Pulls </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/3">Tshirts </a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            User
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/clients/myaddresses">Mes adresses</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/clients/orders">Mes commandes</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/clients/favorites">Mes favoris</a>
            <a data-no-turbolink="true" class="dropdown-item" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Déconnection</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-link">
          <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <a href="/clients/cart">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>  
            </a>       
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <a href="/clients/favorites">
              <i class="fa fa-heart nav-heart"></i>  
              <span id="likes_counter">3</span>
            </a>          
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="/admin/products">Site admin</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you add popper.js in your project ?

Comment: yes it is required in my application.js

Comment: can you give me simple html code in form of pen or fiddle ?

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: bro, dropdown perfectly worked in my system

Comment: It doesn't work on mobile only...

Comment: bro its looking perfect and work in mobile also

Comment: let me add answer

Comment: okay so not on my iPhone... I tried safari and chrome... :(

Comment: ok it will perfectly work in android ! do you check in android ?

Comment: No I only have one phone which is an iphone

Comment: let me try wait a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfect, if you found any problem, comment below !!

**FOR IPHONE & IPAD  USERS**

if in your browser, dropdown doesn't work, add

> href="#"

in your `dropdown-toggle` class, so it works fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light nav-upper-clients">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MarketWeb</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/4">Accessoires </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/5">Chemises </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/2">Pantalons </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/1">Pulls </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/clients/categories/3">Tshirts </a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
            Nelly
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/clients/myaddresses">Mes adresses</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/clients/orders">Mes commandes</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/clients/favorites">Mes favoris</a>
            <a data-no-turbolink="true" class="dropdown-item" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Déconnection</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-link">
          <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <a href="/clients/cart">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>  
            </a>       
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <a href="/clients/favorites">
              <i class="fa fa-heart nav-heart"></i>  
              <span id="likes_counter">3</span>
            </a>          
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="/admin/products">Site admin</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i added href="#" in dropdown, some of the safari users told that it works so i ask to you !

Comment: that is working ! thanks you should update your answer  and explain so it could help anyone else :)  Thank you very much

Comment: i glad to help you